# nginx: conditional proxy_cache based on upstream header

Tags: nginx, cache

Is it possible to configure nginx so that `proxy_cache` is only active when upstream is setting a specific HTTP header? And maybe even use the TTL set in the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`proxy_no_cache`](https://nginx.org/r/proxy_no_cache) to set criteria for which nginx will not cache the response. It accepts arbitrary variables, and will not cache if any of the variables is not empty or not zero.

For example, you may send a response header "Dont-Cache: true", and configure nginx with:

```
proxy_no_cache $sent_http_dont_cache;
```

To set the cache TTL, you can send an [`X-Accel-Expires`](https://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_valid) response header.

Comment: Actually it seems you can use `X-Accel-Expires` for not caching as well: `The “X-Accel-Expires” header field sets caching time of a response in seconds. The zero value disables caching for a response.`. I'll test it.

Comment: If that's all you need to do, then yes, you can just do that. But nginx can also decide not to cache on its own, given other criteria passed to `proxy_no_cache` so you may find that useful in some other context.